# Limit to infinity of product of square matrices equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a sequence of nonzero square matrices, neither diagonal nor lower/upper triangular, $\boldsymbol{A_1},\boldsymbol{A_2},\ldots \boldsymbol{A_j}$ what is a sufficient condition on the eigenvalues of the matrices $\boldsymbol{A_i}$ for:

$\lim_{j \rightarrow\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{j}\boldsymbol{A_i}=0$.

and why?

Comment: For example, that all $A_i$ are strictly upper-triangular.

Comment: There is a matrix norm and a real number $r<1$ such that no matrix $A_i$ has norm larger than $r$.

Comment: @Peter can you give me the rational or a reference on this? Is this related to the eigenvalues of the matrices $A_i$?

Comment: If $\operatorname{Ker}(A_{i+1})⊆\operatorname{Im}(A_i)$ for any $i$, then $A_{i+1}⋅A_{i}=0$.

Comment: The matrices are in general non diagonal/upper/lower triangular, maybe I should edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $‖⋅‖$ be a [**sub-multiplicative** matrix-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) (for example the Frobenius norm), then

$$\log\left\|∏_{j=1}^n A_j\right\| ≤ \log∏_{j=1}^n ‖A_j‖ = \sum_{j=1}^n\log‖A_j‖ $$

Therefore, if $\lim\limits_{n→∞}∑_{j=1}^n\log‖A_j‖ = -∞$, then $\lim\limits_{n→∞}  ∏_{j=1}^{n} A_j = 0$. In particular, this is the case if $‖A_j‖<1-ε$ for all $j$ for any $ε>0$, as @Peter mentioned in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What I am looking for is a condition similar to the one in @Peter's comment, concerning the eigenvalues of the matrices $A_i$, with a reference or explanation if possible. Thanks a lot in any case

Comment: @Giorgetto You can find out about the relationship of matrix-norms and eigen/singular-values in the linked wikipedia-article. In the future, I'd recommend you to first think about what is the actual precise question is you want to ask before you post it (seeing there are 3 close flags already).